# Django passing URLS, getting error NoReverseMatch Reverse for ''drui'' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: django, reverse

I am new to Django so this may be a simple problem. I am trying to pass a url to another class in my views.py. This url is just a PK id from my database table. I keep getting an error that says:

```
Reverse for ''drui'' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found
```

My code is below:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^drui/(?P<disease_id>\d+)/$', 'myapp.views.drui', name='drui')
```

**HTML**

**drui_index.html**

```
<form class="disease_form" action="{% url drui_index %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-block">
  {{ diseaseForm.as_table }}         
  </div>
</form>
```

**drui.html**

```
<form class="disease_form" action="{% url 'drui' disease_id.id %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-block">
   {{ diseaseForm.as_table }}
   {{ indicatorInlineFormSet.as_table }}  
</div>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def drui_index(request):
    diseaseForm = DiseaseForm(request.POST)

    if diseaseForm.is_valid():
       new_disease = diseaseForm.save()
       url = reverse('drui', kwargs={'disease_id': new_disease.id})
       return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
       diseaseForm = DiseaseForm()

    return render_to_response("drui_index.html", {'diseaseForm': diseaseForm}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

#I am passing disease_id to the class below
def drui(request, disease_id):

disease = get_object_or_404(Disease, pk=disease_id)
....
```

Comment: Hi danihp, the quotes didn't work for me. If it helps, the error had pointed to the drui.html code {% url 'drui' Physician_UI_disease_id.id %}.

Comment: Also, for the form `action` on `drui_index.html`, you may need to have `drui_index` as `'drui_index'`.

Comment: When I do 'drui_index' in quotes, I get a nomatch reverse for drui_index. No idea why.

Comment: So you're using django 1.4 without using import future, OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check django version. In new [url 1.5 version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) your syntax is right. Samples:

```
{% url 'arch-summary' 1945 %}
{% url 'full-archive' 2007 %}
```

For previous [1.4 url version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns):

```
{% url arch-summary 1945 %}
{% url full-archive 2007 %}
```

Comment: I am using 1.4, so I dropped the single quotes on my {% url drui disease_id.id } but I still get the same error.

Comment: just tested it again by hardcoding a number: { url drui 2 } and it works. However, that means that disease_id.id isn't working. This may be an issue with the diseaseForm.save() line. Rather than trying to grab an existing record, it is making a new one. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: If i implement the latter, the error message I get is:Reverse for 'drui' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'disease_id': <Disease: df>}' not found. It does not give me the PK for the disease. And if I implement your first option, I get the same error as in my original question.

Comment: @user2646813, sorry. Erased previous comment. Listen: you should inform to template about `disease_id`, you should do it into `render_to_response` dict parameter, something like replace ` {'diseaseForm': diseaseForm},`  by ` {'diseaseForm': diseaseForm, 'disease_id': **here the value** }, `. Also remember to change `"{% url 'drui' disease_id.id %}"` by `"{% url 'drui' disease_id %}" ` in template.

Comment: If I put the  {'diseaseForm': diseaseForm, 'disease_id': here the value }, what should I do with url = reverse and return HttpResponseRedirect(url)? When I comment out, nothing happens when I submit.

Comment: I have vote to close your question. A minimal knowledge is needed. Try to split your question in several question. Step by step. Bye.

Answer (score 1):

Why would `disease_id` have an `id` attribute? That only works if `disease_id` is an actual `disease` object and then you mis-named it? If it's not a `disease` object, then you may want to try using just `disease_id` in the url action. If you think it's an object, and not a number, try printing it out in a `<p>` in the HTML.

Comment: thanks jheld. I believe you are right in that disease_id does not have an id attribute. This is probably why I cannot call the pk/id. I solved this question but came up with another error about this attribute id. The question is here if you have time to help me out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045410/django-object-get-reverse-for-with-arguments-and-keyword-arguments