# Django Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'}' not found Error

Tags: django

I am new to Django and am trying to have a user select from a drop-down of choices, then have their choice pass to my next view class so that the record can be edited. Right now my code passes the name of the disease but not the PK from the database. It seems like a simple problem but I'm not sure how to solve it. I get the following error:

```
 Reverse for 'drui' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Code is below:

**views.py**

```
def drui_index(request):
    diseaseForm = DiseaseForm(request.POST)

    if diseaseForm.is_valid():
       #the problem is probably in the below line. The code isn't right.
       new_disease = diseaseForm.cleaned_data['disease']
       url = reverse('drui', kwargs={'someApp_disease_id': new_disease.pk})
       return HttpResponseRedirect(url)

    else:
       diseaseForm = DiseaseForm()

    return render_to_response("drui_index.html", {'diseaseForm': diseaseForm}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))



def drui(request, someApp_disease_id):

    disease = get_object_or_404(Disease, pk=someApp_disease_id

    if request.method == "POST":

       diseaseForm = DiseaseForm(request.POST, instance=disease)
       indicatorInlineFormSet = IndicatorFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=disease) 
       if diseaseForm.is_valid():
          new_disease = diseaseForm.save(commit=False)   

          if indicatorInlineFormSet.is_valid():
             new_disease.save()
             indicatorInlineFormSet.save()
             return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(valdrui))

    else:
       diseaseForm = DiseaseForm(instance=disease)
       indicatorInlineFormSet = IndicatorFormSet(instance=disease)

    return render_to_response("drui.html", {'diseaseForm': diseaseForm, 'indicatorInlineFormSet': indicatorInlineFormSet, 'hide_breadcrumb': hide_breadcrumb},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**forms.py**

```
class DiseaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
disease = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Disease.objects.all())

class Meta:
   model = Disease
```

**urls.py**

```
 url(r'^drui_index/$', 'someApp.views.drui_index', name='drui_index'),
 url(r'^drui/(?P<someApp_disease_id>\d+)/$', 'someApp.views.drui', name='drui')
```

**HTML for drui.html**

```
<form class="disease_form" action="{% url drui someApp_disease_id %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ diseaseForm.as_table }}
    {{ indicatorInlineFormSet.as_table }}
```

**HTML for drui_index.html**

```
<form class="disease_form" action="{% url drui_index %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
 {{ diseaseForm.as_table }}
```

**UPDATE**

Solved it by adding a .pk in my kwargs. But now I get a Reverse for 'drui' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: What of urls.py? Also do you have any 3rd party apps installed?

Comment: I just added my urls.py and HTML snippets. I don't have any 3rd party apps installed. I read from another posting that my disease_id may not have an id attribute, and that is why it is not passing the PK. I'm not sure if that's correct or how to resolve it

Comment: try and use the same name for the view function argument, and url regex definition, e.g `url(r'^drui/(?P<disease_id>\d+)..`   and `def drui(request, disease_id):`

Comment: Thanks vikki, I am using the same ids for the view function and url regex definition. I updated the code above to reflect that. I'm using django 1.4 if that's valuable. I know there are some differences in url handling in 1.5 and people tend to use {% load url from future %}. However, I get the same error

Comment: you have changed your application. you initially wanted to submit to `drui` but are now submitting to `drui_index` , yes the error is gone but this was not your intended workflow was it?

Comment: Vikki, you are correct. Checking my database, none of my changes were saved when I was on the drui webpage. It only redirected me to drui_index. I will delete my last update so that the code remains concise.

Comment: @user2646813 You do, in fact, want to submit to drui_index. In the updated code, you need to (at least) have `new_disease = diseaseForm.save()` inside the `.is_valid()` branch in the index view. But this question is waaaay too tangled to take this further, I'm pretty sure there's other issues too, please start a new question if it's still broken after that change.

Comment: @user2646813 nevermind about the save - misunderstood the workflow. The issue is still the `{% url %}` tag reversing in the `drui.html` looking for a nonexistent variable, but please open a new question for only that issue.

Comment: AdamKG, having diseaeForm.save() always creates a new disease. My goal is just to have a dropdown where a user can pick from a selection of disease in the database. I will submit a new question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: the new question is here and much cleaner: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048033/django-reverse-mismatch-reverse-for-with-arguments-and-keyword-argum

Comment: This is the same question you asked [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048661/django-forms-reverse-for-with-arguments-7-and-keyword-arguments-not) and the answer is also exactly the same. You need to quote your url name in your template ag.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose that 'drui' is another method in the views.py which contain another template you want to redirect to that when diseaseForm.is_valid()

views.py

```
from django.core import urlresolvers
def drui_index(request):
diseaseForm = DiseaseForm(request.POST)

if diseaseForm.is_valid():
   new_disease = diseaseForm.cleaned_data['disease']
   url = urlresolvers.reverse('drui', kwargs={'disease_id': new_disease})
   return HttpResponseRedirect(url)

else:
   diseaseForm = DiseaseForm()

return render_to_response("drui_index.html", {'diseaseForm': diseaseForm}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: How is this different?

Comment: using urlresolvers.reverse not simple reverse , if you want to redirect.

Comment: he probably imported like this `from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse`

Comment: tell him to show up the whole code and the 'drui' method if exist, that the question.

Comment: I am using urlresolvers.reverse to no avail. The problem may be that my disease_id does not have an id attribute for me to call. But I'm not quite sure how to get the attribute.

Comment: he doesn't have to show each and every thing, that is discouraged here. the error is related to actual view reversing so we know he's using the correct reverse method.

Comment: sure, just posted it up. I only posted the first 2 lines, as the rest doesn't have much to do with the problem. The first 2 lines show the passing of the id attribute.

Comment: @user2646813 Sorry, not enough. post the rest. It's in the `return` that the appropriate context variable isn't being set.

Comment: Okay, I added the rest of drui. I think the problem is that there is no pk for new_disease in my drui_index. If I get rid of the .pk in new_disease.pk, I get error "Reverse for 'drui' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'someApp_disease_id': <Disease: someDisease>}' not found." So something was retrieved. But I need the PK not the disease name.

Comment: @user2646813 In your HTML, change the form action to `{% url drui_index %}`. `someApp_disease_id` isn't defined, and *can't* be when you're rendering the form, because the id hasn't yet been assigned. You're still posting to the index view, then redirecting to the detail (drui) view.

Comment: Thanks! It fixed it, however, when I put url drui_index, it redirects me to the index page. Which is the point of your code. If I redirect {% url drui_index %} to another page, I get another NoReverseMatch. I'm not sure if I'm passing the parameters incorrectly or if my form action is wrong. I'll post the code up in my original question

Comment: @user2646813 you seem to have mixed up the errors. the error in your question is probably coming from the template but the one you've posted here as a comment is coming from your view where you try to use the reverse method. You have two different errors here. First of all changing the form action to drui_index will not fix any of them, it will just make the error go away. It's not clear which disease_id you are trying to use in your form action, or even how you are trying to make it accessible to your template.

Answer (score 0):

As I've mentioned before, it at least seems that `cleaned_data` is just returning a `CharField`, and not a `model`, and thus you're passing through an empty `.pk`.

Comment: That's not actually the issue - it's in the form post action's {% url %} tag. The clue is that the reverse error is complaining about an empty string - that's the template's fallback, since it's not seeing a `someApp_disease_id` variable. The POST branch of the index view never gets hit.

Comment: And yeah, technically, all he needs here is to have that be `{% url drui_index %}` as the form's action attr, but hoping pointing towards the template context for debugging will make the request -> post -> redirect flow clearer for the asker.

Comment: But again, that means that the parameter he's passing through as `someApp_disease_id` is a `''`, correct? And that means that the `.pk` is not an actual attribute of `new_disease` as it currently is being set. Am I reading the code & error right or am I missing something that you're trying to point out?

Comment: `new_disease` never exists - it errors out while rendering the template, he never gets to the point of submitting the form. the `''` comes from Django's (ill-advised imo) fallback to an empty string when a variable lookup doesn't find anything.

Comment: I updated the html code so that there is one for drui.html and drui_index.html. The original question was drui.html, which hopefully wasn't confusing anyone.

Answer (score 0):

In `drui.html` you are referring to `someApp_disease_id` which doesn't exist in the context, this gives you your first error, the one in the original question. To fix this, simply make it available.

I don't know which id is supposed to be stored in this variable but you should have something like this in the `drui` view

```
return render_to_response("drui.html", 
              {'diseaseForm': diseaseForm,
              'indicatorInlineFormSet': indicatorInlineFormSet,
              'hide_breadcrumb': hide_breadcrumb,
              'someApp_disease_id': new_disease.id}, //<<-add this
              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When you added `.pk` to the `drui_index` view, you fixed the other issue (`"Reverse for 'drui' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'someApp_disease_id': <Disease: someDisease>}' not found."`) which allowed you to go to the second error which is the one I have fixed above. So basically you should add the above to `drui` and leave the `.pk` in `drui_index`. That should cure your problems.