# Django forms Reverse for '' with arguments '(7,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: django

I have been running into this error for the past day and can't seem to solve it.

```
Reverse for '' with arguments '(7,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

My goal is to have a user select a disease from my drui_index page. Then the user is taken to the drui page to add or edit the indicators. In my models, there are multiple indicators for each disease. When I get to the drui page, I get the error above and am not sure why. The '7' in the error is the PK from the disease table.

**Views.py**

```
def drui_index(request):
   disease_list = Disease.objects.all()
   context = {'disease_list':disease_list}
   return render(request, 'drui_index.html', context)


def drui(request, disease_id):
   disease = get_object_or_404(Disease, pk=disease_id)  

   if request.method == "POST":

      diseaseForm = DiseaseForm(request.POST, instance=disease)
      indicatorInlineFormSet = IndicatorFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=disease)

      if diseaseForm.is_valid():
         new_disease = diseaseForm.save(commit=False)
         indicatorInlineFormSet.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('drui', kwargs={'disease_id':disease_id}))

   else:
      diseaseForm = DiseaseForm(instance=disease)
      indicatorInlineFormSet = IndicatorFormSet(instance=disease)

   return render(request, 'drui.html', {'disease':disease, 'diseaseForm':diseaseForm, 'indicatorInlineFormSet': indicatorInlineFormSet})
```

**HTML drui.html**

```
 <form class="disease_form" action="{% url drui disease.id %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  {{ disease }}
  {{ diseaseForm.as_table }}
  {{ indicatorInlineFormSet.as_table }}
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^drui_index/$', 'Physician_UI.views.drui_index', name='drui_index'),
url(r'^drui_index/(?P<disease_id>\d+)/$', 'Physician_UI.views.drui', name='drui'),
```

**forms.py**

```
class DiseaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    disease = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Disease.objects.all())

    class Meta:
       model = Disease

IndicatorFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Disease, 
    Indicator,
    can_delete=False,
    extra=MAX_INDICATORS)
```

In my views.py, I don't think I need to call the diseaseForm because I have already chosen a disease in drui_index. However, I don't think that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing quotes around url name:

```
{% url drui disease.id %}
```

Should be (if you are using django >= 1.5) or using `{% load url from future %}` in template:

```
{% url "drui" disease.id %}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `url` tag should be `{% url "drui" disease_id=disease.id %}`, because you need to pass in the keyword argument.

See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#url) for more information.

As you never save the new entry, I think you are just using the form to display the `ModelChoiceField`, in that case you don't need a `ModelForm`:

```
class DiseaseForm(forms.Form):
    disease = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Disease.objects.all())
```

That way, you avoid the `commit=False` part.

You should always have an `else` for your `if form.is_valid()`:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def drui(request, disease_id):
   disease = get_object_or_404(Disease, pk=disease_id)
   ctx = {}
   ctx['disease'] = disease  
   ctx['indicatorInlineFormSet'] = IndicatorFormSet()
   ctx['diseaseForm'] = DiseaseForm()

   if request.method == "POST":

      diseaseForm = DiseaseForm(request.POST)
      indicatorInlineFormSet = IndicatorFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)

      if diseaseForm.is_valid():
         return redirect('drui', disease_id=disease_id)
      else:
         # Form wasn't valid, return the same view to display the errors
         ctx['diseaseForm'] = diseaseForm
         ctx['indicatorInlineFormset'] = indicatorInlineFormset 
         return render(request, 'drui.html', ctx)

   else:

       return render(request, 'drui.html', ctx)
```

Comment: That is not a hard and fast rule.. If you pass arguments in same order django will assign it even to the keywords arguments in same order.

Comment: "Explicit is better than implicit" - The Zen of Python.

Comment: I know that's not how it works in Python, but this is `Django`. Django do this silently if you check the source code. I agree Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Burhan. I will make the necessary changes to keep with best practices.